# How to split a string given a list of positions in Scala

Tags: string, scala, collections

How would you write a *funcitonal* implementation for `split(positions:List[Int], str:String):List[String]`, which is similar to `splitAt` but splits a given string into a *list* of strings by a given list of positions?

For example

- `split(List(1, 2), "abc")` returns `List("a", "b", "c")`
- `split(List(1), "abc")` returns `List("a", "bc")`
- `split(List(), "abc")` returns `List("abc")`

Comment: I'd use a solution based on `substring` instead of `splitAt`. The former will reuse the original `String` in memory, while the latter will copy the the strings into new strings. The provided solutions can be adapted to use `substring`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
def lsplit(pos: List[Int], str: String): List[String] = {
  val (rest, result) = pos.foldRight((str, List[String]())) {
    case (curr, (s, res)) =>
      val (rest, split) = s.splitAt(curr)
      (rest, split :: res)
  }
  rest :: result
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

```
def lsplit(pos: List[Int], s: String): List[String] = pos match {
  case x :: rest => s.substring(0,x) :: lsplit(rest.map(_ - x), s.substring(x))
  case Nil => List(s)
}
```

(Fair warning: not tail recursive so will blow the stack for large lists; not efficient due to repeated remapping of indices and chains of substrings.  You can solve these things by adding additional arguments and/or an internal method that does the recursion.)

Comment: Thanks. I will to make a tail recursive version of your solution.

Comment: @Michael - Might want to also consider adding a `startAt` index so you can `s.substring(startAt,x) :: lsplit(rest, s, startAt+x)` (in the non-tail-recursive version, of course).  If you do, don't forget the `Nil` case.

Answer (score 2):

How about ....

```
def lSplit( indices : List[Int], s : String) = (indices zip (indices.tail)) map { case (a,b) => s.substring(a,b) }

scala> lSplit( List(0,4,6,8), "20131103")
List[String] = List(2013, 11, 03)
```